# Vue.js - How to add components inside rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to format a Wordpress-based website editor from being fully pre-rendered to being rendered through Vue.JS.
The editor's backend (done in PHP) sends me the HTML of the elements on the page. I want to render the page with Vue.js templates/components, with the HTML from the backend, for each element.
It would look something like:

```
<template>
    <div v-html="element.htmlContent"></div>
</template>
```

The problems is that these elements can also have children. Not only that, but some of the elements with children (for example accordions) could look like this:

```
<parent>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <child></child>
    </div>
</parent>
```

Or

```
<parent>
    <div class="wrapper1">
        ...
            <div class="wrapperN">
                <child></child>
            </div>
        ...
    </div>
</parent>
```

Where the divs that wrap the child element belong to the parent element (in the HTML sent by the server).

Here's a real-life example of the object I'm supposed to convert into a component based interface.

```
{
id: 1,
html: "<div>%%%%THIS_SHOULD_BE_REPLACED_WITH_COMPONENT_BASED_ON_CHILD_HTML_WITH_ID_2%%% ... </div>",
children: [
    {
        id: 2,
        html: "<div>This is the final content</div>",
        children: []
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        html: "<div>%%%%THIS_SHOULD_BE_REPLACED_WITH_COMPONENT_BASED_ON_CHILD_HTML_WITH_ID_5%%%</div>",
        children: [
            {
                id: 5,
                html: "<div>This is the final content</div>",
                children: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        html: "<div><div>%%%%THIS_SHOULD_BE_REPLACED_WITH_COMPONENT_BASED_ON_CHILD_HTML_WITH_ID_6%%%</div><div>%%%%THIS_SHOULD_BE_REPLACED_WITH_COMPONENT_BASED_ON_CHILD_HTML_WITH_ID_7%%%</div></div>",
        children: [
            {
                id: 6,
                html: "<div>This is the final content</div>",
                children: []
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                html: "<div>This is the final content</div>",
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Now the question is: How do I render these children INSIDE the parent's HTML while also having them as components?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [hydration](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/hydration.html)?

Comment: Didn't know about that. I'll check it out and see if it helps. Thanks!